# Having trouble understanding API documentation

Tags: javascript, curl

I am currently reading API documentation. It has following way of explaining on how to use it.

1. How to retrieve results

   `https://api.demo.com/v2/tests`
2. Sample request

   `curl -X GET "https://api.demo.com/v2/tests" \
   -u "API_TOKEN:"`
3. Output of above curl command in json.

This documentation does not explain how to use it in different languages. I want to use it in JavaScript but it does not have any details about it. **Anyone who could help me out with this?**

Comment: https://github.com/mikeal/request might help

Comment: You **cannot** use it on **client-side** (including client JavaScript) due to the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy). Otherwise, if you use server-side script, you can do it without any problem since all CURL options are [described in detail](http://curl.haxx.se/docs/manpage.html).

Answer (score 0):

In client-side JavaScript you can use the `XMLHttpRequest` object to send your request to the API and get results back. You have to set a callback function that will run when the request is done (actually each time the request state changes, see https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest for details), for simplicity's sake the one in this example only prints the results to the console.

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
var myXhrCallback = function() {
    if (xhr.readyState == 4) 
        console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }
};
xhr.open("GET", "SOME_URL", true, "AUTHENTICATION_USERNAME", "AUTHENTICATION_PASSWORD");
xhr.send();
// After a while the result will get printed to the console
```